# Issue loading relative path of image in javafx

Tags: java, image

I have issue with relative path to my `arrow.png`.

I have the following set up of directories:

```
--resources
  --arrow.png
  --Accounts.txt
--src
  --Main.java
```

And in my `Main.java` I am trying to load image like this:

```
Image image = new Image("resources/arrow.png");
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

Which is suprising, as couple of lines above it, I load another file like this:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("resources/Accounts.txt");
```

And it works..

Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: what is the package of Image ? Just look at the source code to see what happens this constructor

Comment: import javafx.scene.image.Image;

Comment: did you try with Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/arrow.png")); ?

Comment: Try using the constructor: [Image(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image(java.io.InputStream)). Does the problem repeat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply replace this code:

> Image image = new Image("resources/arrow.png");

with this

> Image img = new Image("file:resources/arrow.png");

Comment: This is yet the simples answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
Image image = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("resources/arrow.png"));
```

Comment: this actually throws : Error:(183, 47) java: no suitable constructor found for Image(java.net.URL)
    constructor javafx.scene.image.Image.Image(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.net.URL cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
    constructor javafx.scene.image.Image.Image(java.io.InputStream) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.net.URL cannot be converted to java.io.InputStream)

Comment: try this Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/arrow.png"));

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ImageIO, personally I think it is simpler to use:

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/arrow.png"));
```